# php is not returning data on angular http request while it does on direct call

Tags: php, angularjs

Dear Stackoverflow community.

I have been dealing with this issue for days now, searching for answers in plenty of forums and blogs but did not find any yet. Seems I am missing something fundamental. So here is my first ever forum question:

I want Angular $http to call a php file and process the response.
When I call the php file directly in the browser, I get the expected output like so:

```
{"records":[{"id":"My ID"}]}
```

As soon as I call the very same file with Angular $http via my Angular controller (I know this is kind of outdated), I will get nothing but a status code "200 OK".

This is my code so far:

PHP return_json.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

// DEBUG MODE
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$id = "My ID";

$data = '{';
$data .= '"id":"'  . $id . '"';
$data .= '}';

echo '{"records":[' . $data . ']}';

?>
```

HTML/JS (Angular)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  
        <title>
   TEST // Angular http with PHP
  </title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/test.css" />        
 </head>

    <body ng-app="testAjax" ng-controller="testAjaxCtrl">
 

<!-- --------------------- 
    HEADER
---------------------- -->
        <header>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>TEST: Angular http</h1>
            </div>
        </header>

<!-- --------------------- 
    SECTION Test Form
---------------------- -->
        <section id="">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h2>Test Form</h2>
                        <form name="test" action="" method="" novalidate>
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>Input Params</legend>
                                <input type="text" ng-model="testParam" name="testName" placeholder="Input testParam" />
                            </fieldset>
                            <button ng-click="getServerAnswer()">submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h2>Angular Scope Values</h2>
                        <p>Name: {{testParam}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
      
    </body>

<!-- --------------------- 
    SCRIPT
---------------------- -->
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="assets/js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular -->
<script src="assets/angular/angular.1.6.10.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/angular/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Test Angular http */
    var app = angular.module('testAjax', ['ngSanitize']);

    app.controller('testAjaxCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

        // call return_json.php
        $scope.getServerAnswer = function(){
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'return_json.php'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
                alert("successCallback");
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            });
        }

    });
</script>
    
</html>
```

What am I missing?
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: please define you angular file in header.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I assume this is more like a general recommendation. I did so, but this does not solve my issue.